# Button in bootstrap form overflows div on small screens

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

The button extends out past the `div` between small and medium (576-768) screens. Cannot figure out why.

```html
 <div class="container">
      <div class="row freebie">
        <div class="col-sm-6 pic42">
          <img src="./Resources/images/42_questions.png" class="imgfree" alt="Responsive image">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <form>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="name" class="form-label">Your name</label>
              <input type="name" class="form-control" id="ame" aria-describedby="name">
              <div id="name" class="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone else.
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="email" class="form-label">Your email</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2 m-2 ">Send my cheatsheet</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

There's no CSS specific to the form.

Comment: Can you include a screenshot that demonstrates the problem you're having? From your code snippet, I'm not seeing any obvious overflow. Also, the image referenced in your code is not accessible publicly, so the result is a broken image. You might want to try replacing it with a publicly-accessible URL in your example.

Comment: I just got a message saying I can't add images as I'm new to the Stackoverflow so it's sending a link. I hope this is helpful. Tried to redo the message but can't see it here. So I'm adding the link here http://127.0.0.1:5500/indexhst.html.   You can use dev tools  to demonstrate the problem with responsiveness. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Aaron. Apologies if the last message isn't clear. Stackoverflow blocked edits. Hopefully the link will demo the problem.  Also - the image is on my computer. I will launch from github through Netlify so it will work from there. I'd give you a link to Github but I can't push at the moment due to the new security measures.

Answer (score 0):

Attribute `style="overflow: hidden"` on that button div should work, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Kenny. I just tried it with no success. It's so weird - I can manipulate that button to do lots of things, just not that. I also can't center it but I'm just not going to worry about that :).

Comment: I ran your code and as far as the center part goes you can just add some padding to that button div, and I found something that might help your other problem, I found it on here so I'm posting the link in case it works so they can have the credit....
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41250173/16709692
.....and I ran the code with the button div like this and it seemed to work fine, but you can play with the padding and get it just how you need it.....
<div class="" style="padding: 20px;">
          <button type="submit" class="" style="white-space: nowrap;"></button>
          </div>
good luck

Comment: Hi Kenny
Thanks again. Tried all that but it hasn't made any difference to anything. I do think it must be something to do with bootstrap's classes because it's only weird in that short size space. I will take a look again tomorrow - all out of patience for it now.

Comment: Alrighty no worries you will get it hang in there.